# LSTM architecture for anomaly detection

Tags: python, lstm, tensorflow, autoencoders, anomaly-detection

I'm testing out different implementation of LSTM autoencoder on anomaly detection on 2D input.
My question is not about the code itself but about understanding the underlying behavior of each network.

One of the two seems to give almost "to good to be true" results and I'm skeptical on whether it's actually the case or if it's just learning an identity function.

**Model 1:**

```
class LSTM_Detector(Model):
  def __init__(self, flight_len, param_len, hidden_state=16):
    super(LSTM_Detector, self).__init__()
    self.input_dim = (flight_len, param_len)
    self.units = hidden_state
    self.encoder = layers.LSTM(self.units,
                  return_state=True,
                  return_sequences=True,
                  activation="tanh",
                  name='encoder',
                  input_shape=self.input_dim)
    
    self.decoder = layers.LSTM(self.units,
                  return_sequences=True,
                  activation="tanh",
                  name="decoder",
                  input_shape=(self.input_dim[0],self.units))
    
    self.dense = layers.TimeDistributed(layers.Dense(self.input_dim[1]))
    
  def call(self, x):
    output, hs, cs = self.encoder(x)
    encoded_state = [hs, cs] # see https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/rnn  
    decoded = self.decoder(output, initial_state=encoded_state)
    output_decoder = self.dense(decoded)

    return output_decoder
```

**Model 2:**

```
class Seq2Seq_Detector(Model):
  def __init__(self, flight_len, param_len, hidden_state=16):
    super(Seq2Seq_Detector, self).__init__()
    self.input_dim = (flight_len, param_len)
    self.units = hidden_state
    self.encoder = layers.LSTM(self.units,
                  return_state=True,
                  return_sequences=False,
                  activation="tanh",
                  name='encoder',
                  input_shape=self.input_dim)
    
    self.repeat = layers.RepeatVector(self.input_dim[0])
    
    self.decoder = layers.LSTM(self.units,
                  return_sequences=True,
                  activation="tanh",
                  name="decoder",
                  input_shape=(self.input_dim[0],self.units))
    
    self.dense = layers.TimeDistributed(layers.Dense(self.input_dim[1]))
    
  def call(self, x):
    output, hs, cs = self.encoder(x)
    encoded_state = [hs, cs] # see https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/rnn 
    repeated_vec = self.repeat(output)
    decoded = self.decoder(repeated_vec, initial_state=encoded_state)
    output_decoder = self.dense(decoded)

    return output_decoder
```

I fitted this 2 models for 200 Epochs on a sample of data `(89, 1500, 77)` each input being a 2D aray of `(1500, 77)`. And the test data `(10,1500,77)`. Both model had only `16 units`.

Here or the results of the autoencoder on one features of the test data.

**Results Model 1:** (black line is truth, red in reconstructed image)

[image]

**Results Model 2:**

[image]

I understand the second one is more restrictive since all the information from the input sequence is compressed into one step, but I'm still surprise that it's barely able to do better than predict the average.

On the other hand, I feel Model 1 tends to be more "influenced" by new data without giving back the input. see example below of Model 1 having a flat line as input :

[image]

PS : I know it's not a lot of data for that kind of model, I have much more available but at this stage I'm just experimenting and trying to build my understanding.

PS 2 : Neither models overfitted their data and the training and validation curve are almost text book like.

Is anyone able to explain why there is such a gap in term of behavior ?

Thank you

**EDIT 1:**

Here are the results of Model 1 benchmarked against a baseline model returning `x[t] = x[t-1]`

1. Benchmark on the initial data (not difference):

Model 1: MSE = 0.0985

[image]

Baseline : MSE = 0.0312

[image]

2. Same exercise but using the difference `x = x[t]-x[t-1]`

Model 1: MSE = 0.0175

[image]

Baseline: MSE = 0.0609

[image]

Comment: Does this time series exhibit [tag:stationarity]? What happens if you predict the first differences *change* instead of the level?

Comment: @Sycorax, the one on the graph is stationary. Among the 77 features I'd say they are too except for one or 2 may be. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by predicting change instead of level ? Should I feed the time diff `x[t]-x[t-1]` to the model instead ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. It's common for folks to train NNs on the level (e.g. a stock ticker price) instead of the change (e.g. the return), and discover trivially good results. When the time series is non-stationary, it's easy to get deceived because the trivial model is just using $x_{t-1}$ as the prediction $\hat{x}_{t}$. Basically, this is how it can happen that "One of the two seems to give almost "to good to be true" results and I'm skeptical on whether it's actually the case or if it's just learning an identity function."

Comment: @Sycorax Agree, I'm going to give it a try by using the diff see if it sheds any light. I'm a skeptical guy though :). I understand regular NN might be fooled by trend in the data because they lack the capacity to carry information across time steps and long sequence. But aren't RNN or LSTM free from such limitation ?

Comment: LSTMs are flexible models for sequences, but they're not perfect. I think it's more accurate to say that an LSTM can learn to *reproduce* the previous value, if that pattern is well-supported by the data. In this case, it appears to be so. One way to quantify this is to measure your error for a model that uses $x_{t-1}$ to predict $x_t$, since this reflects the baseline error for a model that just reproduces the past. If you can meaningfully beat that model, you're making progress.

Comment: @Sycorax, Ok that make sense, the model could be returning x[t-1] for x[t] and this might give the impression of a perfect fit when instead everything is just shifted from one time step. Good point, I'll update the post after the benchmarking.

Comment: @Sycorax, post has been updated !